# How to create an animation that would be triggered by click

Tags: css

How can I achieve the following effect: when a user clicks a link he'll see the content of the current page slowly move up and away then new content of the next page appear instead. I'd prefer to use only CSS if possible.

Comment: Use css transitions - see https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Feb/22/Using-CSS-Transitions-to-SlideUp-and-SlideDown

Comment: Create a CSS class for the fade-in transition, and another for the fade-out transition. Use jQuery to add the appropriate classes to the appropriate content containers.

Comment: It means you have to stop the link, make the animation, and relaunch the link. You'll need JS for that, not CSS.

Answer (score 2):

A CSS-only solution can be achieved with transitions. Here's **[the example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpOvYq)** and the code is as follows:

**CSS**

```
.message {
    background:#181818;
    color:#FFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: -250px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: top 300ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    }

.message h1 {
  color:#FFF;
}

#toggle {
  position:absolute;
  appearance:none;
  cursor:pointer;
  left:-100%;
  top:-100%;
}

#toggle + label {
  position:absolute;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:10px;
  background: #26ae90;
width: 100px;
border-radius: 3px;
padding: 8px 10px;
color: #FFF;
line-height:20px;
font-size:12px;
text-align:center;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
cursor: pointer;
  margin:20px 50px;
  transition:all 500ms ease;
}
#toggle + label:after {
  content:"Open" 
}

.container {
transition: margin 300ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
  padding:5em 3em;
}

#toggle:checked ~ .message {
  top: 0;
}

#toggle:checked ~ .container {
  margin-top: 250px;
}

#toggle:checked + label {
  background:#dd6149;
}

#toggle:checked + label:after {
  content:"Close"
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="toggle" />    
<label for="toggle"></label>      
<div class="container">
  <h1> Click the Open button to see hidden mesage.</h1>    
</div>
<div class="message">
  <h1> hello, I'm a hidden message. You found it.</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: @Raoulito what do you mean?

Comment: Muhammad writes: “when a user clicks a link” and further “content of the next page appear”, so I assume he's talking about `<a>` link tags. Your answer would not work with `<a>` tags default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

**HTML** Include all your pages in a `<main>` div (or else)

```
<body>
    <main>
        <a href="http://thevolumeproject.com">some link</a>
    </main>
</body>
```

**CSS** make the `<main>` in fixed position, and the size of the window

```
main {
    position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('a').click(function(event){ // when click on any link <a>
    event.preventDefault(); // prevents <a> natural behavior (sending you somewhere)
    var URL = $(this).attr('href'); // stores the <a> href attribute
    $('main').animate({top:'-=100%'},1000,function(){ // moves up <main> and when it's gone…
        window.location.href = URL; // sends you where you belong
    });
});
```

Cheers!

```js
$('a').click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
    var URL = $(this).attr('href');
 $('main').animate({top:'-=100%'},1000,function(){
        window.location.href = URL;
    });
});
```

```css
main {
    position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background-color: #DDD;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main>
    <a href="http://thevolumeproject.com/">some link</a>
</main>
```